# How to Center Facebox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I like to center facebox on a project im working on. when i added this code it will center

```
  $(document).bind('close.facebox', function() {
    $(document).unbind('keydown.facebox')
    $('#facebox').fadeOut(function() {
      $('#facebox .content').removeClass().addClass('content')
      $('#facebox .loading').remove()
      $(document).trigger('afterClose.facebox')
    })
    hideOverlay()
  })
```

problem is it will load on top then move to center. is there anyway to make the facebox load on center? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Facebox plugin makes it already in center
http://phpcode.eu/images/1312914393.png

Comment: i meant the height. check the "Ajaxes" example. it's coming on top